# How to minimize Windows Live Mail to the system tray?

Tags: windows, windows-live-mail

How do I minimize Windows Live Mail to the system tray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running Windows 7, you're probably looking for [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19438/minimize-Windows-live-mail-to-the-system-tray-in-Windows-7/).

Comment: Link only answers can become useless when the link gets broken. please consider editing your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Right click to Windows Live Mail -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Check Rund this... square -> Chech Windows Vista Service Pack 2 and then click apply. Restart Windows Live Mail and then try to minimize it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by doing

1. Right-click the tray icon of Windows Live Mail
2. Check the option: Hide window when Inbox is minimized
3. Minimize the main window

That should do it

Comment: First, thanks for your reply. However, the options I have on the context menu I get from the windows live mail icon from tray doesn't include the one you mention. I am using Windows 7, btw. Any other idea? Thanks.